# Stack images on top of each other when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid list of images that can be dragged and sorted in order. You select and drag multiple items by CTRL+CLICK. The problem is that it becomes clunky when dragging 3+ images. Is there a way of stacking these images when dragging?

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"/></li>
    // more li items
</ul>
```

JS

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('ul').multisortable();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KWeMM/679/

**Update:**

I've updated the raw plugin so that it stacks the images. The problem is it won't place them properly when dropping. It's clunky.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/50fd0u8h/3/

```
        var masterEle = $('.' + settings.selectedClass).eq(0).position();
            masterLeft = masterEle.left,
            masterTop = masterEle.top;

        var siblingTop = masterTop, siblingLeft = masterLeft;

        // fix to keep compatibility using prototype.js and jquery together
        $.fn.reverse = Array.prototype._reverse || Array.prototype.reverse

        var height = 0;
        $('.' + settings.selectedClass, parent).filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('i') < myIndex || $(this).data('i') > myIndex ;
        }).reverse().each(function() {
            height = $(this).outerHeight();
            siblingTop = siblingTop+5;
            siblingLeft = siblingLeft+5;
            zIndexSet = zIndexSet-5;
            $(this).css({
                left: siblingLeft,
                top: siblingTop,
                position: 'absolute',
                zIndex: zIndexSet,
                width: ui.item.width()
            });
        });
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this - http://jsfiddle.net/arvinddhakad/50fd0u8h

Comment: @ArvindDhakad Thanks, i'll try it. At the bottom of the newly updated version there is this `jQuery(function($){
    $('ul').multisortable();
}); `

Comment: @ArvindDhakad awesome plugin by the way. I've updated it so it has a stack effect. The problem I have is that it won't drop the images properly, it's a little clunky http://jsfiddle.net/50fd0u8h/3/